# Hyperlinks in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

In Google Sheets, it is possible to add a hyperlink to a cell as:

```
 =hyperlink("www.google.com";"search the web")
```

This will show the text search the web which will hyperlink to Google.

1. Can this rule be inserting into the middle of a cell?
2. Is it possible to make a rule like this in your spreadsheet so that anytime you type, "search the web", you automatically get the hyperlink to Google (you don't have to keep adding `=hyperlink("www.google.com";"search the web")`)?
3. If that's possible, is there any way to add a parameter to the URL?

Answer (score 3):

The only sense in which a hyperlink can be placed in the *middle* of a cell is by centering the cell. If what you mean is a cell containing a hyperlink and also other plain text, that is not currently possible.

Parameters can be used in a URL. A URL is simply a string and can be a constant value or can be built up from functions or other cells. For example:

```
= hyperlink( "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & B2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/search?q="&A13&L13&"&safe=active",A13)
```

A13 uses whatever text is in the cell to search. It is also at the end of the formula to name the cell the formula is in.

I've got “near my address” (well, “near _______”, whatever your address is) in cell L13, just remove `&l13` to get rid of it. It searches Google for the text in cell a13 near my location.

This searches Google Maps for the text near my location:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/maps?q="&A13&L13&"&safe=active",A13)
```